# A ZK Performance Monitor

Tags: performance, slf4j, monitor, zk

We have requirement to monitoring performance in our application .I found the link [A ZK Performance Monitor](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/Small_Talks/2010/January/A_ZK_Performance_Monitor) but i am unable to configure this.Actually i want to configure performance monitoring in my application with slf4j logger .Anyone can share steps to configure for the same.( zk 7.0.1)

I am trying to create the `CommandPhaseListener`  for this case .But i am not sure where we implements the `CommandPhaseListener` class in our application to track performance .Actually we want to monitoring the performance in slf4j logger.

```
package support.mvvm;

import org.zkoss.bind.*;
import org.zkoss.zk.ui.Executions;

public class CommandPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {

    @Override
    public void prePhase(Phase phase, BindContext ctx) {
        if (phase== Phase.COMMAND){
            Executions.getCurrent().setAttribute("command", ctx.getCommandName());
            System.out.println(ctx.getCommandName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void postPhase(Phase phase, BindContext ctx) {

    }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: what have you done so far? what isn't working from your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you didn't registered the listener in zk.xml:

```
<zk>
    <library-property>
        <name>org.zkoss.bind.PhaseListener.class</name>
        <value>support.mvvm.CommandPhaseListener</value>
    </library-property>
</zk>
```

Comment: can you please give me the steps to configure the monitor in slf4j